# Divide String over 2 custom Rect shapes in onDraw();

Tags: android, android-canvas, rect, drawtext

I'm having issues dividing my String object over 2 Rect shapes.

Firstly i have no idea how to set canvas.drawtext to a specified region. 
Like you would do if you use textview.

Secondly I can only calculate / break my string at the width of the Rect shape. 
meaning I can only draw 1 line instead of filling out the box... 
I could take the box height and divide it by the textsize to calc the number of lines that fit, 
but then i would have to draw line by line ?

surely there must be examples for this , but i cannot seem to find them.

somewhat the situation :

View :

[xxxxx]----------

[xxxxx]----------

----------[xxxxx]

----------[xxxxx]

i  want a very long string to be divided and placed at the [xxx] boxes

ta.